# cut particular pointed string using php

Tags: php

How I cut the extra 0 string from those sample.

current string: 0102000306
required string: 12036

Here a 0 value have in front of each number. So, i need to cut the extra all zero[0] value from the string and get my expected string. It’s cannot possible using str_replace. Because then all the zero will be replaced. So, how do I do it?

Comment: How did you decide to keep the zero in the middle, but not the others? The algorithm is not quite clear to me.

Comment: You want to remove all zeros that do not occur in a sequence of zeros and replace all sequences of zero with a single zero?

Comment: you can also loop through string and can make if condition and generate new string

Comment: basically not.i just need to filter the 1,3,5,6,7..sub sequence values.and keep the 2,4,6,8,10,12..value..that's it

Comment: @riad, that still makes no sense, you mentioned 6 twice .. noone will be able to help you unless you make yourself clear.

Comment: ohhh..sorry...its basically should be  filter the 1,3,5,7,9..sub sequence values.and keep the 2,4,6,8,10,12..value..that's it –pls help

Comment: loop through the elements, only taking the even numbered elements. What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$currentString = '0102000306';
$length = strlen($currentString);
$newString = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
   if (($i % 2) == 1) {
      $newString .= $currentString{$i};
   }
}
```

or

```
$currentString = '0102000306';
$tempArray = str_split($currentString,2);
$newString = '';
foreach($tempArray as $val) {
   $newString .= substr($val,-1);
}
```

Comment: sorry second one is not working properly.it's showing Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @riad - fixed the second suggestion... str_split() rather than chunk_split()

Answer (score 4):

Using a regex:

```
$result = preg_replace('#0(.)#', '\\1', '0102000306');
```

Result:

```
"12036"
```

---

Using array_reduce:

```
$string = array_reduce(str_split('0102000306', 2), function($v, $w) { return $v.$w[1]; });
```

---

Or array_map+implode:

```
implode('',array_map('intval',str_split('0102000306',2)));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not particularly elegant but this should do what you want:

```
$old = '0102000306';
$new = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($old); $i += 2) {
  $new .= $old[$i+1];
}
echo $new;
```